# How to expose LWC to flow builder

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-web-components

I'm looking for ways to expose one LWC to flow  builder to drop it on a screen component. Anyone aware of any such attribute that needs to be set in LWC Meta.xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make the components available in flow screens, edit the lightning web component configuration file to include [a target](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) of *lightning_FlowScreen*. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Example Flow Component</masterLabel>
  <description>This lwc is available in flows.</description>
  <targets>
      <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

See the [Winter ‘20 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_solutions.htm) for more information.

Comment: Metadata configuration documentation for LWC in flows can now be found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_flow_screens and here: https://unofficialsf.com/adding-lightning-web-components-to-flow-screens/

Answer (score 6):

As per the documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_experiences 
LWC is not supported in Visual flows as of now!

As mentioned, you can wrap a lightning web component in an aura component, and can use the same in flows, and in many other experiences and tools where LWC is not supported!

**Update:** Now LWC is supported in flows from Winter' 20 updates, as the feature has been implemented.
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_solutions.htm

Comment: Would it not be possible if I wrap the LWC inside an aura component which I can drop in flow? Just a thought.

Comment: @AshishSharma Yes, its possible, I had updated the answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Winter '20 Salesforce release will allow you to embed Lightning Web components to flow builder.

Answer (score 2):

LWC is not supported yet with flow in this version. See official [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_experiences) for this. You have to use Aura component for your requirement.